# Pass data from child to parent process without pipe

Tags: c, linux

I was told that we can pass value `v` by using `exit(v)` in the child process and `wait()` in the parent process, then retrieving `v` by using `WEXITSTATUS()`. I've looked through the web and couldn't get a solution. Any ideas or code would be useful.

Comment: Since two functions were named to you, a good place to start would be to read their documentation.  Especially [`wait()`'s](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Comment: I should say, however, that inter-process communication is by no means a subject for a beginner.  The approach that has been suggested to you is about the simplest form of IPC I can think of, but still....

Comment: Note that you are limited to passing a value between 0 and 255 via `exit()` — unless you go through a far more elaborate process than you're ready to deal with, and then you only get 4 bytes instead of 1 transferred.

Answer (score 1):

A close to minimal solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        exit(42);   // The Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything
    }
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("PID %d exited with status %d\n", corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            printf("PID %d died from signal %d\n", corpse, WTERMSIG(status));
        else
            printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X (which is neither exited nor terminated)\n",
                   corpse, status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produced:

```
PID 28883 exited with status 42
```

Note that you can only pass values 0..255 via `exit()` on POSIX systems unless you get into deep shenanigans with `sigaction()`, `SIGCHLD`, `SA_SIGINFO` and so on (and even then you only get 4 bytes of data).  YMMV on Windows systems.